# java change the document in DocumentListener

Tags: java, swing, jtextcomponent, documentlistener, documentfilter

I use a `DocumentListener` to handle any change in a `JTextPane` document. while the user types i want to delete the contents of `JTextPane` and insert a customized text instead. it is not possible to change the document in the `DocumentListener`,instead a solution is said here:
[java.lang.IllegalStateException while using Document Listener in TextArea, Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788779/java-lang-illegalstateexception-while-using-document-listener-in-textarea-java)
,but i don't understand that, at least i don't know what to do in my case?

Comment: DocumentLister is to `listen` to the changes to Document, not to change it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`DocumentListener` is really only good for notification of changes and should never be used to modify a text field/document.

Instead, use a [`DocumentFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter)

Check [here](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter) for examples

**FYI**

The root course of your problem is that the `DocumentListener` is notified WHILE the document is been updated.  Attempts to modify the document (apart from risking a infinite loop) put the document into a invalid state, hence the exception

**Updated with an example**

This is VERY basic example...It doesn't handle insert or remove, but my testing had remove working without doing anything anyway...

[image]

```
public class TestHighlight {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestHighlight();
    }

    public TestHighlight() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane(new DefaultStyledDocument());
                ((AbstractDocument) textPane.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new HighlightDocumentFilter(textPane));
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(textPane));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }

        });
    }

    public class HighlightDocumentFilter extends DocumentFilter {

        private DefaultHighlightPainter highlightPainter = new DefaultHighlightPainter(Color.YELLOW);
        private JTextPane textPane;
        private SimpleAttributeSet background;

        public HighlightDocumentFilter(JTextPane textPane) {
            this.textPane = textPane;
            background = new SimpleAttributeSet();
            StyleConstants.setBackground(background, Color.RED);
        }

        @Override
        public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset, String text, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
            System.out.println("insert");
            super.insertString(fb, offset, text, attr);
        }

        @Override
        public void remove(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length) throws BadLocationException {
            System.out.println("remove");
            super.remove(fb, offset, length);
        }

        @Override
        public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {

            String match = "test";

            super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs);

            int startIndex = offset - match.length();
            if (startIndex >= 0) {

                String last = fb.getDocument().getText(startIndex, match.length()).trim();
                System.out.println(last);
                if (last.equalsIgnoreCase(match)) {

                    textPane.getHighlighter().addHighlight(startIndex, startIndex + match.length(), highlightPainter);

                }

            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: i want to make a change in it's document after that  notification

Comment: From what I understand, the DocumentFilter will allow you update the Document as it is been changed

Comment: This will allow you to remove text and insert new text and filter out unwanted text

Comment: each time that user types a key, i want to get the complete text in the `JTextPane`, then empty the field, insert customized text(just the text which had been entered but some keywords are colored), i think DocumentFilter is not a good suggestion for this case, what do you think?

Comment: The short answer is, yes. The long answer is, what exactly are you trying to accomplish? Are you modifying the text pane the user is typing into or another field?

Comment: I want to modify the textPane the user is typing into, and i told you what the modify is (coloring keywords)

Comment: Ah, so as a "word" matches some kind of requirement, you want to modify the attributes around the word to highlight then?

Comment: [Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html) in the middle of the document (based on JTextArea, but doesn't matter, concept is the same, similair)

Answer (score 5):

> while the user types i want to delete the contents of JTextPane and
>   insert a customized text instead.

- this isn't job for [DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html), basically this [Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/handling.html) is designed to firing events out from [JTextComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html)s to the another JComponent, to Swing GUI, implemented methods in used Java
- have look at [DocumentFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter), this provide desired methods to change, modify or update own [Document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Document.html) (model for [JTextComponents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html)) on runtime

Answer (score -1):

Wrap the code you call in `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`

Comment: This could lead to an infinate loop, where the user updates the document, then the program updates the document, then the program updates the document, then...:P

Comment: @MadProgrammer you can define flag or remove the listener and readd it after action is done.

Comment: heheheheheh `SO Forum` againts `King of JTextComponents`, I'm going to adopt, have to wait a see who wins :-)

Comment: @mKorbel Where's Kelopatra when you need her ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer notice `@kleo` is `Princessin of Compound JComponents`

Comment: @MadProgrammer here :-) Yeah, it _can_ be done, but is dirty enough to merit a downvote (Stan, you have been waiting for it, didn't you :-) - my problem is not the dirtyness as such, but dirtyness without need.

Comment: @kleopatra it's really my -1 for the dirty solution. Not sure how to avoid it e.g. when we have to replace abbreviation with full text.

Comment: what's wrong with a DocumentFilter, isn't that the clean path?

Comment: How to remove old content in the DocumentFilter?

Comment: might be missing something but ... implement the filter's replace as needed? Taking your example of an abbreviation: find its start, change the offset to that and adjust the replacement length and change the text to the full word.

Comment: Ok, May be you are right in the case. Another example then. Imagine a table in the beginning of the document. User hits ENTER. MS WOrd creates a paragraph _before_ the table (not in the first cell). That requires first processing the user typings and then restructure DOM hierarhy elements (moving the paragraph top be before the table). It can't be done in the filter. And I don't think my solution is hack. 1. We detect some condition in the listener 2. we start some action _after_ the original change 3. we prevent unnecessary event triggering. What's wrong with this?