# How to color keywords in a Java text editor?

Tags: java, swing, colors, text-editor, jtextpane

I have a small working text editor written in Java using JTextPane and I would like to color specific words. It would work in the same fashion that keywords in Java (within Eclipse) are colored; if they are a keyword, they are highlighted after the user is done typing them. I am new to text editors implemented in Java, any ideas?

Comment: This is quite a complex task, if you can find a 3rd party library, that would greatly simplify the problems.  Having said that, you could take a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19399904/set-hilighting-color-in-jtextfield/19401765#19401765) and [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727548/java-change-the-document-in-documentlistener/14727657#14727657) if you really wanted to try your hand at it...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Don't make it complex. Use `JSyntaxPane` instead ;-) I know you are a simple person. :-P

Comment: @LittleChild It's not about me, it's what the OP wants ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Make it easy for everyone ?? :P

Comment: @LittleChild The OP may not be to use 3rd party libraries so demonstrating a single choice may actually be a bad choice.  Besides, once the realise the complexity of the task, they may actually decide a 3rd party library is what they need.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I actually did highlight the complexity :D

Answer (score 1):

> In computer science, lexical analysis is the process of converting a
>   sequence of characters into a sequence of tokens. A program or
>   function that performs lexical analysis is called a lexical analyzer,
>   lexer, tokenizer,[1] or scanner. A lexer often exists as a single
>   function which is called by a parser or another function, or can be
>   combined with the parser in scannerless parsing.

Having said that, it is no trivial task. You need a high level library to do that. It will ease your task. What is the way out ?

Use [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/about.html). Here is what its site says:

> ANTLR is a powerful parser generator that you can use to read,
>   process, execute, or translate structured text or binary files. It’s
>   widely used in academia and industry to build all sorts of languages,
>   tools, and frameworks....
>   NetBeans IDE parses C++ with ANTLR.

There, problem solved. The author of ANTLR also has a book on how to use ANTLR which you may want to buy if you wanna learn how to use it.

*Having given you enough brain melt, there is an out of the box solution available for you: [JSyntaxPane](http://code.google.com/p/jsyntaxpane/). Just like any JCOmponent, you initialize it and pop it into a JFrame. It works like a charm. It supports a whole lot of languages apart from Java*