# Syntax highligting on specific keywords

Tags: java, swing, editor, jtextpane

I am trying to make a little editor and I need some syntax highlighting on some specific keywords. I hope you will have the patience to look through this. I want to highlight just the word from the .txt file in my JTextPane. I need a way to solve this and hope you can point me to the right direction.

I started by making this .txt file:

```
if
else
echo
return
global
for
```

Reading the .txt file here and also do some checking:

```
import javax.swing.text.DefaultStyledDocument;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Ilhami on 22-11-2014.
 */
public class SyntaxHighlighter {
    final static Charset ENCODING = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
    private List<String> lines;

    public SyntaxHighlighter() {
        try {
            lines = readFile("keywords.txt");
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.getStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public boolean keywordMatch(List<String> lines, String word) throws IOException {
        boolean isTrue = false;
        for(String item : lines) {
            if(!item.isEmpty() && !word.isEmpty()) {
                if(item.equals(word)) {
                    return isTrue = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return isTrue;
    }

    public List<String> readFile(String file) throws IOException {
        Path path = Paths.get(file);
        return Files.readAllLines(path, ENCODING);
    }

    public List<String> getLines() {
        return this.lines;
    }
}
```

I have tried something but I keep getting an exception when I type something in my JTextPane(yeah I am using Swing, not sure if that's a good idea).

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempt to mutate in notification
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.writeLock(AbstractDocument.java:1338)
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.replace(AbstractDocument.java:658)
    at javax.swing.JTextPane.replaceSelection(JTextPane.java:192)
    at javax.swing.JTextPane.replaceSelection(JTextPane.java:175)
    at Editor$MyDocumentListener.appendToPane(Editor.java:61)
    at Editor$MyDocumentListener.setFont(Editor.java:70)
    at Editor$MyDocumentListener.insertUpdate(Editor.java:81)
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.fireInsertUpdate(AbstractDocument.java:201)
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.handleInsertString(AbstractDocument.java:748)
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.insertString(AbstractDocument.java:707)
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.replace(AbstractDocument.java:669)
    at javax.swing.JTextPane.replaceSelection(JTextPane.java:192)
    at javax.swing.JTextPane.replaceSelection(JTextPane.java:175)
    at javax.swing.text.DefaultEditorKit$DefaultKeyTypedAction.actionPerformed(DefaultEditorKit.java:884)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.notifyAction(SwingUtilities.java:1663)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBinding(JComponent.java:2879)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindings(JComponent.java:2926)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2842)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4883)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1954)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:806)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1074)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:945)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:771)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4754)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

This is my Editor class where I am getting the error:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Ilhami on 22-11-2014.
 */
public class Editor {
    private JFrame editor;
    public JTextPane editorPane;
    private SyntaxHighlighter syntaxHighlighter;
    private List<String> lines;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;

    public Editor() {
        editor = new JFrame("Editor");
        editorPane = new JTextPane();
        editor.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        editor.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(editorPane);

        syntaxHighlighter = new SyntaxHighlighter();
        lines = syntaxHighlighter.getLines();

        editorPane.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new MyDocumentListener());

    }

    public void showEditor() {
        editor.add(scrollPane);
        editor.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        editor.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        editor.setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        editor.setVisible(true);
    }

    class MyDocumentListener implements DocumentListener {
        private StyledDocument document;

        Style style, style2;
        public MyDocumentListener() {
            document = editorPane.getStyledDocument();
            editorPane.setDocument(document);
        }

        private void appendToPane(JTextPane tp, String msg, Color c, int len)
        {
            StyleContext sc = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext();
            AttributeSet aset = sc.addAttribute(SimpleAttributeSet.EMPTY, StyleConstants.Foreground, c);

            aset = sc.addAttribute(aset, StyleConstants.FontFamily, "Lucida Console");
            aset = sc.addAttribute(aset, StyleConstants.Alignment, StyleConstants.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED);

            len = tp.getDocument().getLength();
            tp.setCaretPosition(len);
            tp.setCharacterAttributes(aset, false);
            tp.replaceSelection(msg);
        }

        public void setFont() {
            try {
                for (String string : editorPane.getText().split("\\s+")) {
                    if (syntaxHighlighter.keywordMatch(lines, string)) {
                        appendToPane(editorPane, string, new Color(12, 146, 20), 40);
                    } else {
                        appendToPane(editorPane, string, new Color(22, 22, 22), 40);
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.getStackTrace();
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            setFont();
        }

        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            setFont();
        }

        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            //System.out.println("Hej");
        }
    }
}
```

Last but not least my Main.java file:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Editor editor = new Editor();
                editor.showEditor();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a DocumentFilter instead

Comment: Let me try this instead and see if it works.

Comment: Maybe something like [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19399904/set-hilighting-color-in-jtextfield/19401765#19401765)