# how to keep focus on jframe when jtextfield or button are selected

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, setfocus

like the title says. I'm trying to figure out how to keep the focus on the JFrame or perhaps the window. So that when I press F1 on the keyboard, it activates a method. And it should also do it when I'm typing in a textfield.

I have read through the "How to Use the Focus Subsystem" but can't find what I'm looking for. Or maybe I just don't know where to look.

I tried using `contentPane.setFocusable(true);` but it looses focus when I activate another component. So how do I get it to keep focus?

Comment: Don't use a key listener for this; use key bindings or `frame.getRootPane().setDefaultButton()`

Comment: a KeyListener is more flexible and you can map more responses than with setDefaultButton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be trying to solve the wrong problem caused by using a [`KeyListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html), which requires focus. Instead, use [key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) or [`setDefaultButton()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7457102/230513), found in the frame's root pane.

Addendum: *I tried key bindings, and solved it almost. It still does not work when a* `JTextField` *is selected. Do you maybe have a solution for that?*

Depending on your needs, consider a [`DocumentListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) or [`DocumentFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter). See this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14727548/230513) for more on the two.

Comment: A KeyListener does not bring troubles...and can be used by more than one component

Comment: @alex2410 Again...a KeyListener does not bring troubles, key binding is a suitable solution, but not the only one.

Comment: thanks for the respons. I agree with you that keylistener is not the way to go. I tried setDefaultButton. But that seemed to work for only one key(I should have mentioned that i also want F2, F3 etc. to work). So I tried keyBindings, and solved it almost. It still does not work when a JtexField is selected. Do you maybe have a solution for that?

Comment: @Slang2856223 whats the word?? let me hear it!!! k k k k ...keeeeeyliiiisteneeersss

Comment: @Slang2856223: key bindings are the more flexible approach; more above for `JTextComponent` subclasses.

Comment: @trashgod no they're not