# Java - how to interrupt input from keyboard when i write in jtextpane

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I would interrupt input from keyboard when i write in jtextpane because before to write a character i would apply a style into a document and after insert this character. I do this with keyListener but every time i press one button on the keyboard the result is two character: one from System.in and one from listener with style.

I hope I explained myself 
Thanks

Comment: Use a DocumentListner when you want to be notified of changes to the component or use a DocumentFilter to change or filter what is been send to the field. If you want to add special keys (like ctrl+b), use the key bindings API

Comment: DocumentListener is a good solution to apply style but System.in isn't interrupt and i have two input evey moment.

Comment: Why are you using `System.in` in a GUI!?  It's not really the best solution for an event driven environment

Comment: i don't use system.in. i'm implementing a complex text editor. When user writes into a JTextPane i would catch character from keyboard with keylistener, apply current style to a character and next insert into textpane, but there are two input: one comes from keyboard and one from my keylistener

Comment: The solution of MadProgrammer is the one and he should make it an answer. I especially recommend DocumentFilter.

Comment: DocuemntFilter is what you're looking for

Comment: Maybe something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727548/java-change-the-document-in-documentlistener/14727657#14727657)

Comment: Thanks to all. i will use documentfilter and seteditable(false) for jtextpane