# How do I change the colour of certain words when they are entered into a JTextPane?

Tags: java, swing, styles, jtextpane

I've seen several posts on this, but none seem to work.

I have a thread on the Java Programming Forums about this, please help!: http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/whats-wrong-my-code/47440-trying-make-simple-java-editor-having-trouble-changing-colour-words.html

Comment: what is the question ?

Comment: How do I change the colour of certain words when they are entered into a JTextPane? Sorry, I should've been more clear on this.

Comment: please check the answer

Comment: Please read stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking your next question.

Comment: Have a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727548/java-change-the-document-in-documentlistener/14727657#14727657)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DefaultStyledDocument document = new DefaultStyledDocument();
JTextPane textpane = new JTextPane(document);
StyleContext context = new StyleContext();
// build a style
Style style = context.addStyle("test", null);
// set some style color
StyleConstants.setForeground(style, Color.RED);
// add some data to the document
document.insertString(0, "", style);


OR




JTextPane pane = new JTextPane();
SimpleAttributeSet set = new SimpleAttributeSet();
StyleConstants.setForeground(set, Color.red);
Document doc = pane.getStyledDocument();
doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "Kleine ", set);
```

Comment: I'm accessing the doc.insertString part in a different function then everything else, and I'm getting a NullPointerException on it. I had it like this to debug: doc.insertString(0, "", style); with each of the different parts on a new line, and it had it on the function itself.

Comment: why do you need doc in document.insertString(0, "", style); in different function ?

Comment: i have tried one more option, edited my answer please check

Comment: Because I have a method that detects Java things like 'if' and 'for'. And that other one doesnt work either.